# Avoid js error message when using a common js file

Tags: jquery

I use several jquery plugins on my website, most of which are actually used only on some pages. For instance a image slider plugin that is only displayed on the starterpage.

Then I have a common file "custom.js" in which I call the functions from and it is included on every page similar to a external css style sheet. I prefer to keep it in one file and the size is not substantial.

But since I do not want to include every js-plugin file, which are sometimes quite big, on pages were the actual plugin arent displayed my problem appears. The common js file will try to call the plugins which are not included which generate a js error message: e.g. `$("#slider").coinslider is not a function`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You say that some pages don't use those functions, but clearly the page in question is trying to, so your question contradicts itself.

Comment: @lwburk hehe calm now, read the question again, the page is not using it but the common js file that is included on every page calls it and thus the error message appear

Comment: @Joesph - By definition, if a script your page loads is using it, then the page is using it.

Comment: @lwburk haha is this adding value to the thread?

Comment: @Joesph - Maybe, if it inspired you to write a clearer question. (I'm not being facetious; I found it hard to figure out what you were asking.)

Comment: @lwburk reformulated it now, hope its more understandable now

Comment: @lwburk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1200/discussion-between-joseph-and-lwburk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest would be to check for the presence of the 'slider' div (assuming this div was only used in one place on your site, when you have the plugin loaded):

```
if($("#slider").length){
    $("#slider").coinslider()
}
```

You could instead catch the error that is being thrown:

```
try {
    $("#slider").coinslider();
} catch(err){}
```

But I would recommend the first method.

Answer (score 1):

With browser caching, this shouldn't be a big issue, cause your script will be loaded only once and it'll be loaded from cache (and not from the server) the next times.

However, the feature you want (autoload, load on demand, or lazy loading) is possible, but a little complicated. Here you can find more information:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/

http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks, but do you think the simple answers above will solve it too? also you are right about the cache of course, how long is it though? parallell to a php session?

Answer (score 0):

You can always encapsule the calls with something like this:

```
if($("#slider").coinslider){$("#slider").coinslider()}
```

or even this might work:

```
if($.coinslider){$("#slider").coinslider()}
```

Basically, check if the function exists before trying to call it.

Of course, try grouping the initializations if used for several elements, since each check do have a slight performance cost.